# What causes this Cannot find control with name error in my Angular 9 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on a "Tasks" aplication in Angular 9 and PHP. I run into this a `Cannot find control with name: <controll name>` error while trying to pre-populate the **update form** with data.

The form looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="updateTask" name="edit_task_form">
  <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Title" formControlName="title" placeholder="Title">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>Short Description</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Short description" formControlName="short-description" placeholder="Short Description">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="tags">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.id">{{category.name | titlecase}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>Full Description</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput formControlName="full-description" placeholder="Full Description"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button mat-flat-button type="submit" color="accent" [disabled]="updateTask.pristine || updateTask.invalid">Update</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

In the component I have:

I am importing these at the top:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from "lodash";
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {SharedService} from "../../../core/services/shared-service.service";
import {ApiService} from "../../../core/http/api.service";
taskId: string;
updateTask: FormGroup;
currentTest:any = {};

 constructor(private _apiService: ApiService, private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, private _formControl: FormControl, private _sharedService: SharedService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.categories = [
  {
    id: 1, name: "Category 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2, name: "Category 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3, name: "Category 3"
  }
];

 this.updateTask = this._formBuilder.group(this.formFields);

 this._apiService.getTaskInfo().subscribe(res => {
   this.Task = res;
   let formInfo = this.Task.info; 

   formInfo.forEach(function(task, index){
    console.log(task.key + ": " + task.data);
    this.updateTask .get(task.key).setValue(task.data);
   }, this)
 });

}
```

The `formInfo` array Im trying to get the task info from looks like this:

```
[{
   "taskId":"5eb45c2738ae2549000ddb0a",
   "key":"title",
   "data":"Lorem ipsum dolor"
},
{
   "taskId":"5eb45c2738ae2549000ddb0a",
   "key":"short-description",
   "data":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"
},
{
   "taskId":"5eb45c2738ae2549000ddb0a",
   "key":"full-description",
   "data":"Reprehenderit aperiam unde distinctio, fuga magnam asperiores laboriosam expedita fugiat numquam rerum debitis temporibus dolores."
}]
```

The line `console.log(task.key + ": " + task.data)` correctly outputs:

```
title: Lorem ipsum dolor
short-description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
full-description: Reprehenderit aperiam unde distinctio, fuga magnam asperiores laboriosam expedita fugiat numquam rerum debitis temporibus dolores.
```

Yet, the form fields are not populated with the data and I get errors in the console:

```
Cannot find control with name: 'title'
```

and so on, for every object in the `formInfo` array.

What have I missed?

---

## UPDATE:

I have simplified the code that should populate the form:

```
currentTask: any = {};

constructor(private _apiService: ApiService, private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, private _formControl: FormControl, private _sharedService: SharedService) {}

updateTask = this._formBuilder.group({});

ngOnInit(): void {

    this._apiService.getTaskInfo().subscribe(res => {
        this.currentTask = res;
        let formInfo = this.currentTask.info;

        formInfo.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(item.key + ": " + item.data);
            this.updateTest.addControl(item.key, this._formBuilder.control(item.data, Validators.required));
        }, this);
    });

}
```

I get a `NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[FormControl -> FormControl -> FormControl]: NullInjectorError: No provider for FormControl!` error in the borwser.

Comment: Do you create FormGroup before you try to set value?

Comment: @BojanKogoj Yes. The line `updateTask: FormGroup` is the second inside the class.

Comment: you're only declaring  updateTask : FormGroup, you need to define its controllers

Comment: @doublezofficial How do I do that?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use formControlName attributes in your template, you must have some FormControls inside your updateTask FormGroup.

Actually this line can't work since you try to retrieve with the `get` method, a nonexistent FormControl :

```
this.updateTask.get(task.key).setValue(task.data);
```

What I advise you to do is instantiating a FormBuilder instance in your constructor to minimize your boilerplate :

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}
```

Create your FormGroup :

```
updateTask = this.fb.group({});
```

*PS : be careful, this line only type the updateTask variable as a FormGroup but it don't make it an instance of the FormGroup class :*

```
updateTask: FormGroup;
```

And then re-use your foreach loop to create all you FormControls :

```
formInfo.forEach((task) => {
  this.updateTask.addControl(task.key, this.fb.control(task.data))
})
```

Since then you should not have the console error anymore !

Here is a simplified and working StackBlitz to helping you solving your problem : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-fromcontrols

Comment: Yeah, you already did `updateTask = this.fb.group({})` but you try to construct your formGroup with default values contained in `this.formFields`. What's inside this variable ?

Comment: It looks like this in my code: ` private formFields: TaskForm = {
    'title':              [null, Validators.required],
    'short-description':  [null, Validators.required],
    'full-description':   [null, Validators.required],
  };`

Comment: I can not see it in the console because I have this error and nothing else visible after it: `NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[FormControl -> FormControl -> FormControl]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for FormControl!`

Comment: Here is the problem, your formFields variable doesn't contain FormControls, you must add a FormControl constructor. You have at least to change your formFields variable to look like this : `private formFields: TaskForm = { title: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required), short-description: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required), full-description: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required) };`

Comment: I cant do `description-short: this._formBuilder.control(null, Validators.required)` it gets underlined with a red squiggly line.

Comment: But the cleanest way in my mind is to instantiate your empty updateTask FormGroup and then add controls with the good default value on your `formInfo.foreach()`. Please look at the stackBlitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-fromcontrols

Comment: You may have to add quotes just like you did before because hyphens are not supported in unquotted property name

Comment: You must delete the private _formControl: FormControl from your constructor to avoid the error

Comment: I did delete that part and now I get those `Cannot find control with name: 'description'` (and so on) error. The line `console.log(item.key + ": " + item.data)` does output the keys and data correctly.

Comment: Did your formControlName attributes have the same value as the keys of your formInfo ?

Comment: Yes, and there is  a match.

Comment: Could you provide me a Github repo or something to test it and try to figure out what's wrong ?

Comment: What id the `formInfo` array has more items that I need to use. Should your solution still work?

Comment: I need my full-description filed NOT to be required. What should I do. And no, there is no  Github repo.

Comment: If you do not want full-description to be required you just have to add a condition on your foreach : `if (item.key === 'full-description) { this.updateTask.addControl(item.key : this._formBuilder.control(item.data)) } else { your actual code }`. Thanks to this, you do not add a full-description FormControl with `Validators.required`

Comment: And if your `formInfo` array has more field than the one you need to use, you should add condition for each of the items items you need (eg: `if (item.key === 'title' || item.key === 'short-description') { add you FormControls to updateTask }`. In order to not create useless FormControls.

Comment: I tried `formInfo.forEach(function(item):any{
        console.log(item.key + ": " + item.data);
        this.updateTask.addControl(item.key, this._formBuilder.control(item.data, item.key != 'tags' ? Validators.required : null));
      }, this);
    });` not it does ot work from some reason. I am so tired at this moment I beerly know what I am doing.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I updated the Stackblitz to match your variables name and added some comments to help you understand. Hope it helps. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-fromcontrols

Comment: That is exactly what I did, but mine does not work for some reason. And of course, the question is a simplified model of the real project, but with all the relevant elements (or so I think). Thanks for the effort. I appreciate it.

Comment: What if I had a dummy array of categories (with which I have updated the question's code), would that be a relevant difference and the cause of the `Cannot find control with name: 'title'` error?

Comment: My form opens in a popup and its logic i inside ngOnInit. That might be the source of my problems. `openForm(event, id): void {
        event.stopPropagation();
        this._matDialog.open(TaskFormComponent, dialogConfig);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

add the following code inside your ngOnIt method

```
this.updateTask=new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl(),
      short-description: new FormControl(),
      full-description: new FormControl()
    });
```

Comment: I have this instead: `this.updateTask = this._formBuilder.group(this.formFields)`, I thought it was enough.

Comment: I don't think that will create controls.

Comment: Using `short-description` is shown as improper, with a red squiggly line. It disappears if I use `short_description` but I have to keep the original.